# How to Get SQL Error message from Adapter.Update (ASP.NET with VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, adapter

Writing an ASP.NET app using VB. My BLL uses Adapter.Update to insert new reocrds. This is turn calls a stored procedure, which returns meaningful messages (e.g. "This invoice already exists") that I want to display to the user.

I can't figure out how to get the message though.

Here's part of my BLL with insert function:

```
    <System.ComponentModel.DataObject()> _
Public Class InvoicesBLL
    Private _invoiceAdapter As Shipping_InvoiceTableAdapter = Nothing
    Protected ReadOnly Property Adapter() As Shipping_InvoiceTableAdapter
        Get
            If _invoiceAdapter Is Nothing Then
                _invoiceAdapter = New Shipping_InvoiceTableAdapter()
            End If
            Return _invoiceAdapter
        End Get
    End Property

' Insert new Invoice
        <System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Insert, True)> _
        Public Function AddInvoice( _
                                   ByVal TripNo As String, _
                                   ByVal TypeID As Integer, _
                                   ByVal VendorID As Integer, _
                                   ByVal InvNo As String, _
                                   ByVal InvAmount As Decimal, _
                                   ByVal InvDate As Date, _
                                   ByVal ID As Integer _
                                   ) As Boolean


            Dim invoices As New AcmeShipping.Shipping_InvoiceDataTable()
            Dim invoice As AcmeShipping.Shipping_InvoiceRow = invoices.NewShipping_InvoiceRow()
            invoice.TripNo = TripNo
            invoice.TypeID = TypeID
            invoice.VendorID = VendorID
            invoice.InvNo = InvNo
            invoice.InvAmount = InvAmount
            invoice.InvDate = InvDate


            invoices.AddShipping_InvoiceRow(invoice)
            Dim rowsAffected As Integer = Adapter.Update(invoices)
            Return rowsAffected
        End Function
```

I changed some data to force an error on next insert and I get an sqlexception. I was hoping there would be an error property or the adapter or something, but I don't see it.

The error I forced was the one below,  it looks like I can get it from System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException but that doesn't seem to have any relevant properties or method

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled by user code
  Class=16
  ErrorCode=-2146232060
  HResult=-2146232060
  LineNumber=148
  Message=Insert Shipping Costs: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. - ErrorNo: 512
  Number=50000
  Procedure=Shipping_Invoice_InsertInvoice
  Server=10.60.2.141,2433
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
  State=1
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatusErrors(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatus(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataRow[] dataRows, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdateFromDataTable(DataTable dataTable, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataTable dataTable)
       at AcmeShippingTableAdapters.Shipping_InvoiceTableAdapter.Update(Shipping_InvoiceDataTable dataTable) in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\372b2bbc\295d1b24\App_Code.6ff9nff6.5.vb:line 4136
       at InvoicesBLL.AddInvoice(String TripNo, Int32 TypeID, Int32 VendorID, String InvNo, Decimal InvAmount, DateTime InvDate, Int32 ID) in S:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SegerdahlShippingInvoices\trunk\App_Code\BLL\InvoicesBLL.vb:line 76
  InnerException:
```

Could someone point me in the right direction for detecting specific exceptions when using adapter.update?

So I figured out where the message is, but don't get why I still get ApplicationException unhandled

My ItemInserted event looks like this:

```
Protected Sub InvoiceInserted(sender As Object, e As DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs) Handles dvInvoice.ItemInserted

        If e.Exception IsNot Nothing Then
            ExceptionDetails.Visible = True
            ExceptionDetails.Text = "There was a problem saving the invoice. "
            If e.Exception.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim inner As Exception = e.Exception.InnerException
                If TypeOf inner Is System.Data.Common.DbException Then
                    ExceptionDetails.Text &= _
                    "Insert Failed." & _
                    "Please try again later."
                ElseIf TypeOf inner _
                 Is System.Data.NoNullAllowedException Then
                    ExceptionDetails.Text += _
                        "There are one or more required fields that are missing."
                ElseIf TypeOf inner _
             Is System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException Then
                    ExceptionDetails.Text += _
                        "Insert Failed." & e.Exception.Message
                ElseIf TypeOf inner Is ArgumentException Then
                    Dim paramName As String = CType(inner, ArgumentException).ParamName
                    ExceptionDetails.Text &= _
                        String.Concat("The ", paramName, " value is illegal.")
                ElseIf TypeOf inner Is ApplicationException Then
                    ExceptionDetails.Text += inner.Message
                End If
            Else
                ExceptionDetails.Text += e.Exception.Message

            End If
            e.ExceptionHandled = True
            e.KeepInInsertMode = True
        Else
            ExceptionDetails.Visible = True
            ExceptionDetails.Text = "inserted. "
        End If

        gvCosts.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

but when I run it, I keep getting the message about ApplicationException unhandled in user code. However, ExceptionDetails DOES display the message. Surely this indicates it's handled?

What am I missing 
Thanks

Mark

Comment: And the `Exception.Message` property does not work for you?

Comment: How does it return the messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the stack trace:

The error occurred in method `AddInvoice` on line 76 of the `InvoicesBLL.vb` file.

UPDATE:

Add `Try-Catch` blocks around the code you want to handle exceptions for, like this:

```
Try
    ' Do database call here
Catch nullEx As NoNullAllowedException
    ' Put logic here for NoNullAllowedException
Catch dbEx As DbException
    ' Put logic here for DbException
Catch sqlEx As SqlException
    ' Put logic here for SqlException
Catch appEx As ApplicationException
    ' Put logic here for ApplicationException
Catch ex As Exception
    ' This is a catch-all block, because all exceptions derive from System.Exception class
End Try
```

Note: With multiple `Catch` the first one that meets the criteria of the exception thrown will match and the others will not be evaluated. This means you want to put more specific exception types (`NoNullAllowedException`) earlier in the list of `Catch` blocks versus more general exception types (`Exception`).

Comment: Thanks Karl, I know exactly where it occurs, but can't find a way to get the message

Comment: Why are you not using `Try-Catch` logic? You can setup multiple `Catch` statements for the types of exceptions you are interested in handling. Then you could get rid of your nested `If` logic and just handle exceptions by type in the `Catch` blocks.